# Django app import models form another file not working

Tags: python, django

Hi I am having a problem with importing a model form another app file that I have in the same project.
I am using the SQLite3 data base

```
-DND_website 
  -data
    -__init__.py
    -models.py  
  -main
    -views.py
```

the code:

`from DND_website.data.models import PagesData`

error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DND_website.data'
```

Comment: You can try `from DND_website import data`.

Comment: have you select your python interpreter correctly ?

Comment: It should be `from data.models import PagesData`, `DND_website` simply looks to be your project name (It is not a package) (The `DND_website` if imported would be the main app of your project i.e. the directory `DND_website/DND_website`)

Comment: You might need an `__init__.py` file in folder `DND_website` too. Even an empty might do.